# open pdf toprint in new tab using javascript in asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hiexperts,

i need your help. i have a web application and i am creating a pdf using itext sharp and trying to print it silently.

after creating the pdf i am tring to print it using the code

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    string baseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

    var urlPdf = Server.MapPath("~/MERGPdf/Merge_doc.pdf");

    PdfReader ps = new PdfReader(urlPdf);

    /*inserts js into pdf*/
    PdfStamper pdf = new PdfStamper(ps, ms);

    pdf.JavaScript = "this.print({bUI: false, bSilent: true, bShrinkToFit: true});";
pdf.Close();


    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
    ms.Flush();
```

but my issue is, the pdf is opening in same window and the user has to click back button to go to page.. how can avoid it..

regards,

Sivajith S.

Answer (score 0):

You can popup a small window... say 400px by 300 Px.... use it to run that piece of code.

once done then you can close it....

you can refer to this and see if it helps...

http://forums.asp.net/t/1287755.aspx/1